# Python RawTurtle not following goto() command

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, turtle-graphics, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create a program where you click on a Tkinter canvas and a RawTurtle moves to the mouse, but my code is not working. The canvas has a Button-1 event binded to it to tell the program the coordinates of the mouse.
But, when you click on the canvas, instead of the turtle going to the mouse, it kind of mirrors what you would expect it to do (moves away from the mosue as if another mosue is being mirrored). Both the event and the turtle position coordinates are the same when they are printed out.

**Code:**

```
import turtle
from tkinter import *


def move(event):
    global t
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
    t.setpos(x,y)
    print(t.pos())
    print(event)
def penState(event):
    global penDown,t
    if penDown == True:
        t.penup()
        penDown = False
else:
    t.pendown()
    penDown = True

def changeWidth(w):
    t.pensize(w)
def changeColour(e=None):
    global colourBox
    t.color(colourBox.get())
    colourBox.configure(fg=colourBox.get())
def doCircle():
    global checkFillIsTrue,circleSizeBox
if checkFillIsTrue.get() == 1:
    begin_fill()
    t.circle(int(circleSizeBox.get()))
    end_fill()
else:
    circle(int(circleSizeBox.get()))
window = Tk('Paint')
window.title('onionPaint')
root = Frame(window)
root.pack(side=LEFT)
cv = Canvas(window,width=500,height=500)
t = turtle.RawTurtle(cv)
t.resizemode('user')
cv.bind('<Button-1>',move)
cv.bind('<Button-2>',penState)
cv.pack(side=RIGHT)
checkFillIsTrue=IntVar()
penDown = True
#Pen width box
sizeLabel = Label(root, text="Pen Width")
sizeLabel.grid()
sizeScale = Scale( root, variable = \
'var',orient=HORIZONTAL,command=changeWidth )
sizeScale.grid()
#Colour box
colourLabel = Label(root, text="Color(HEX or name):")
colourLabel.grid()
colourFrame = Frame(root)
colourFrame.grid()
colourBox = Entry(colourFrame, bd=1)
colourBox.pack(side=LEFT)
colourSubmit = Button(colourFrame,text="OK",command=changeColour)
colourSubmit.pack(side=RIGHT)
#Fill
fillLabel = Label(root,text='Fill')
fillLabel.grid()
fillFrame = Frame(root)
fillFrame.grid()
beginFill = Button(fillFrame,text='Begin Fill',command=t.begin_fill)
endFill = Button(fillFrame,text='End Fill',command=t.end_fill)
beginFill.pack(side=LEFT)
endFill.pack(side=RIGHT)
#Mmore shapes
Label(root,text='Shapes').grid()
#Circle form
Label(root,text='Circle',font=('Heveltica',8)).grid()
circleSize = Frame(root)
circleSize.grid()
circleSizeBox = Entry(circleSize,bd=1)
circleSizeBox.insert(0,'Radius')
circleSizeBox.pack(side=LEFT)
fillCheck = 
Checkbutton(circleSize,text='Fill',variable=checkFillIsTrue).pack(side=LEFT)
circleSizeSubmit = 
Button(circleSize,text='Draw',command=doCircle).pack(side=RIGHT)
#Text form
Label(root,text='Text',font=('Heveltica',8)).grid()
textFrame = Frame(root)
textFrame.grid()

window.mainloop()
```

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a disaster.  You should specifically read up on the 'global' keyword in Python and when it must be used.  And Python code style in general. I believe the key fix to your program is to introduce a TurtleScreen overlay on the canvas and then switch to turtle event handing rather than tkinter event handing.

I've reworked your code below, fixing as many problems as I could:

```
import turtle
from tkinter import *

FONT = ('Helvetica', 8)

def move(x, y):
    terrapin.setpos(x, y)
    print(terrapin.pos())

def penState(x, y):
    global penDown

    if penDown:
        terrapin.penup()
        penDown = False
    else:
        terrapin.pendown()
        penDown = True

def changeWidth(w):
    terrapin.pensize(w)

def changeColour():
    color = colourBox.get()
    terrapin.color(color)
    colourBox.configure(fg=color)

def doCircle():
    radius = int(circleSizeBox.get())

    if checkFillIsTrue.get():
        terrapin.begin_fill()
        terrapin.circle(radius)
        terrapin.end_fill()
    else:
        terrapin.circle(radius)

window = Tk('Paint')
window.title('onionPaint')

root = Frame(window)
root.pack(side=LEFT)

canvas = Canvas(window, width=500, height=500)
screen = turtle.TurtleScreen(canvas)

terrapin = turtle.RawTurtle(screen)

screen.onclick(move, btn=1)
screen.onclick(penState, btn=2)

canvas.pack(side=RIGHT)

checkFillIsTrue = BooleanVar()
penDown = True

# Pen width box
sizeLabel = Label(root, text="Pen Width")
sizeLabel.grid()
sizeScale = Scale(root, variable='var', orient=HORIZONTAL, command=changeWidth)
sizeScale.grid()

# Colour box
colourLabel = Label(root, text="Color(HEX or name):")
colourLabel.grid()
colourFrame = Frame(root)
colourFrame.grid()
colourBox = Entry(colourFrame, bd=1)
colourBox.pack(side=LEFT)
colourSubmit = Button(colourFrame, text="OK", command=changeColour)
colourSubmit.pack(side=RIGHT)

# Fill
fillLabel = Label(root, text='Fill')
fillLabel.grid()
fillFrame = Frame(root)
fillFrame.grid()
beginFill = Button(fillFrame, text='Begin Fill', command=terrapin.begin_fill)
endFill = Button(fillFrame, text='End Fill', command=terrapin.end_fill)
beginFill.pack(side=LEFT)
endFill.pack(side=RIGHT)

# More shapes
Label(root, text='Shapes').grid()

# Circle form
Label(root, text='Circle', font=FONT).grid()
circleSize = Frame(root)
circleSize.grid()
circleSizeBox = Entry(circleSize, bd=1)
circleSizeBox.insert(0, 'Radius')
circleSizeBox.pack(side=LEFT)
fillCheck = Checkbutton(circleSize, text='Fill', variable=checkFillIsTrue).pack(side=LEFT)
circleSizeSubmit = Button(circleSize, text='Draw', command=doCircle).pack(side=RIGHT)

# Text form
Label(root, text='Text', font=FONT).grid()
textFrame = Frame(root)
textFrame.grid()

window.mainloop()
```